# Expected number of occurrences of the pattern $HTH$ in $n$ independent coin tossings

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

I am self-learning calculus-based basic undergrad probability. In *Intro to Probability*, Blitzstein and Hwang, the chapter on expectations and variances has an interesting question on the expected number of occurrences of the pattern $HTH$. I love a challenge, and tried to have a crack at this, but I merely have no ideas, on how to approach it.

Could you guys me a clue/suggestion on how to proceed with such a question, without giving away the entire solution?

> [BH 4.40] In a sequence of $n$ independent fair coin tosses, what is the expected number of occurrences of the pattern $HTH$ (consecutively)? Note that overlap is allowed e.g. $HTHTH$ contains two overlapping occurrences of the pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of the $8$ possibilities of $3$ consecutive independent tosses are equiprobable.

In $n$ tosses, there will be $(n-2)$ such subsequences of $3$ consecutive tosses.

Thus $\Bbb {E}[X] = \frac{n-2}{8}$.

Comment: Thanks! This did cross my mind; but writing down $X=\sum_{j=1}^{n-2}I_j$ initially was confusing, because $I_{j-1}$ and $I_{j}$ are not independent. If $HTH$ occurs at $j-1$, $I_{j-1} = 1$ and $I_{j} = 0$. However, linearity of expectations works regardless.

Comment: I confused the question with no. of moves required to get $HTH$ for first time, which will of course be a constant number. This is correct (linear function of $n$). +1